# How to access AWS S3 data using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am fairly new to both S3 as well as boto3. I am trying to read in some data in the following format:

```
https://blahblah.s3.amazonaws.com/data1.csv
https://blahblah.s3.amazonaws.com/data2.csv
https://blahblah.s3.amazonaws.com/data3.csv
```

I am importing `boto3`, and it seems like I would need to do something like:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

However, what should I do after creating this client if I want to read in all files separately in-memory (I am not supposed to locally download this data). Ideally, I would like to read in each CSV data file into separate Pandas DataFrames (which I know how to do once I know how to access the S3 data).

Please understand I'm fairly new to both `boto3` as well as `S3`, so I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation, which are probably what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have 2 options, both the options you've already mentioned:

1. Downloading the file locally using `download_file`

```
s3.download_file(
    "<bucket-name>", 
    "<key-of-file>", 
    "<local-path-where-file-will-be-downloaded>"
)
```

See [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)

2. Loading the file contents into memory using `get_object`

```
response = s3.get_object(Bucket="<bucket-name>", Key="<key-of-file>")
contentBody = response.get("Body")
# You need to read the content as it is a Stream
content = contentBody.read()
```

See [get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object)

Either approach is fine and you can just chose which one fits your scenario better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(<<bucketname>>, <<itemname>>)
body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```